# Windows phone 8.1 How to load Resources File RESW

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I would like to know if its possible to load a resources file?

I mean. I have currently 2 folders which is fr-FR end en-US.

In each folder, I have a Resources.resw. These 2 files work when I change the language in the setting of the phone. If the phone is in FR or US, It will load the right Resources.resw.

But I would like to know if I can change it inside the application?
Load the right file when user will select fr/en.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the [ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.applicationlanguages.primarylanguageoverride.aspx) to change the language during runtime without restart the phone and application:

```
   private async void ChangeLagButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
        Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name;
        Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
        Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
        await Task.Delay(100);
        //To refresh the UI without restart the phone
        this.Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());          
    }
```

Comment: why await Task.Delay(100)?

Comment: I Use Page.Frame.Navigate(typeOf(MyPage)); The page was reload, but the language was the same, I have to rerun the app to make it work

Comment: That is the function of the Task.Deplay(100), if you do not use it, using the Frame.Navigate for the first time will do not work